# Angular2: Updating the object in Subscriber

Tags: angular, observable

Following is my Parent (General) component which is loading the data from server and binding it to child (Order )component

```
import { Component, OnInit ,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
    import { REST,Response } from '../../../services/rest/rest.service';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @Component({
      selector: 'general',
      template: '<div>
      <div class="order">
         <order [order]="orderData"></order>
      </div>
        </div>',
      styleUrls: ['./general.component.css']
    })

    export class GeneralComponent {
       public orderData: Order = null;
      public static projectDataUrl: string = 'orderViewOrder';


      constructor(private rest: REST) {
          this.loadOrderData();
        }
      }





      private loadOrderData(): any {
            this.rest.getWithStringId(GeneralComponent.projectDataUrl, '123').map(
          (res: Response) => res.json()).
          catch((error:any)=>Observable.throw(error.json()||'Server error')).
          subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.orderData =<Order>data   // here data is set
          this.notifyOthers.emit(this.orderData)},
           err => console.log("Error should get printed \n"+err),
            () => console.log("It should be executed in the end"));

      }



    }

    export class Order {
      communicatedFinishedDate:number[];
      customerId:number;
      estimatedSampleArrival:number[];
      finishDate:number[];
      id:string;
      name:string;
      oldId:string;
      orderNumber:string;
      quoteNumber: string;
      samplesStoredUntil:any;
      startDate:number[];
      type:string;

    }



    }
```

And in the **child component**

```
**OrderComponent**

import { Component, OnInit ,Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Order} from '../../container/general/general.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'order',
  template: '<div>
<div class="order">
<h2 class="label">Order details</h2><br>
<label>Type</label><br>
<span>{{orderData.type}}</span><br>
<label>Services/Characteristics</label><br>
<span>{{orderData.finishDate}}</span><br>
<label>Quote/Offer No</label><br>
<span>{{orderData.quoteNumber}}</span><br>
<label>Order/Purchase No</label><br>
<span>{{orderData.orderNumber}}</span><br>
</div>
</div>',
  styleUrls: ['./order.component.css']
})
export class OrderComponent  {
@Input('order') public orderData: Order;

  constructor() { 

  }




}
```

**Problem :** Parent component is successfully loading the data but in Order Component it is null.

When i debug i can see the data in *this.orderData* .

> As per my understanding Subscriber is like "Async method" 
>   OrderComponent is using the orderData before its even set in
>   Subscriber

(Correct me if i am wrong)

What is the solution then ? i read about Event emitters and tried to do something like this in General Component:

**@Output() notifyOthers: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();**

and in Subscriber :

```
...
subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.orderData =<Order>data
      this.notifyOthers.emit(this.orderData)},
...
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks

**UPDATE** how can i bind the **Not Null data** to Child Component, is there any way to make the instance to wait till we get the data from Subscriber ?

I am checking orderData instance in child component like this:

```
<div class="order">
    <h2 class="label">Order details</h2><br>
    <label>Type</label><br>
    {{orderData===null}}     // returns true
    {{orderData|json}}       // returns nothing
    <span>{{orderData?.type}}</span><br> //**With Operator it shows nothing since orderData is null**
    <label>Services/Characteristics</label><br>
    <span>{{orderData.finishDate}}</span><br>
    <label>Quote/Offer No</label><br>
    <span>{{orderData.quoteNumber}}</span><br>
    <label>Order/Purchase No</label><br>
    <span>{{orderData.orderNumber}}</span><br>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE2** when i debug control goes first in OrderComponent before it actually process the Subscriber function .

Comment: Can you use elvis operator, ?, in your child template and try again? Like `orderData?.type`

Comment: @echonax: thanks for your comment. Elvis operator will just avoid "null exception"  because " orderData" is null in Order Component. I tried it does not help.

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstood, but with solution that I post, your child component is created unless `orderData` is null.

Comment: @ulubeyn : i think i did not explain the problem that well,i want to pass "NOT NULL" data to child component .

Comment: Can you just let me know, what happen when you try my solution, what is the output in debug mode and what do you want to see when debugging?

Comment: @ulubeyn please check updated section in my question

Answer (score 0):

`orderData` is null because your are sending it to child component before it has been setted by subscriber. Try this in your html, this should work (If not, please notify me);

```
...
<div class="order" *ngIf="orderData">
     <order [order]="orderData"></order>
</div>
```

Angular create your component and call your service, but this service is async. When child component is created, your service response has not arrived yet and `orderData` which is null has gone to your child component.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your explanation is right that "response has not arrived yet" but your solution is just avoiding "null Reference" . My point is how can i send the "NOT NULL" data to child component.